# How to create a Dynamic Mapping in Informatica Developer that takes a table/view name as input and exports its data into a flatfile?

Tags: dynamic, mapping, etl, informatica

I have never worked on Developer Client before, and have been only using Powercenter for a few years. I'm trying to automate the export process that I have and I'm trying to understand how to achieve it in Developer. I desire to the accomplish the following:

1. There are various Views defined in our DB which generate reports for our stakeholders.
2. I want to create one mapping (template) that takes the view name as the input (parameter) and export the result of that view into a flatfile (with some customization for Header, Footers, separator and etc).

I have no idea where to start in this regard in the Developer Client. Can you please guide me in the correct direction?

Would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Not a use case for informatica - there are loads of more efficient ways to do this from a stored procedure or a script. Problem is you don't know the list of columns and their data types to start with. When database offers option to extract results as a csv seems pointless to try bend a convoluted solution